# Where can I find removable training wheels?

Tags: wheels, training, rear-wheel, children

Where can I find training wheels that would fit into these slots:

[image]

All the training wheels I've seen online are ones where you have to attach by removing the hex nut on the center of the back wheel.

This is a Huffy 16in bike.

Comment: Do you _need_ to use that block?  It looks like it's just bolted onto the axle, and you could remove the block by removing the axle nut.

Comment: I was thinking about doing, but I'd have to buy a socket wrench set. I guess a socket wrench will come in handy.

Comment: There are several opinions about training wheels - one option is to take the pedals off instead, and treat it like a balance bike until such time as the child gains competence with steering.

Comment: This is well worth a read, start with the idea of how to decide when its time to remove them, and work back down the learning progression....  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/what-are-the-conditions-for-removing-training-wheels?rq=1

Comment: If you have any intent whatsoever of doing any minor repairs around your house (including the bike), owning a simple set of sockets and a wrench isn't a bad use of $20 or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up buying a socket wrench and socket in order to remove hex nut holding the block in place. I bought the wrench on eBay and the socket from Home Depot, which sells individual sockets. With the block out of the way, I installed the type of training wheels that I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 6):

The training wheels that come with the bike are designed for easy assembly on a new bike. They are not sturdy and the only way I know to find a replacement is to get one from another bike, maybe someone who's kid didn't need them anymore.

Some local bike shops will carry 16" training wheels, usually sturdier than stock, and they should install them for you for about the price of a flat tire fix. That would save you needing a wrench set along with the hassle of installation.

The last option is to buy them from somewhere and install them yourself. Maybe a neighbor will loan you some tools.

It's always good to check the bearing adjustments in the rear hub, front hub, crank, and headset as well as having the correct chain tension. These bikes are often adjusted incorrectly from the factory. It can make a big difference on ease of pedaling.