# Replacement Training wheels for Nakamura Kids Bike Options Needed

Tags: children

I purchased a Nakamura kids bikes and realized after that these bikes have a square box blocking where training wheels would go. These bikes have proprietary training wheels that come with bikes when new. Looks like they click in and out. So now I can't add my own. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Could you please add a photo showing the mounting blocks?

Comment: Many people recommend not using them.   Consider if you really need them. Removing the pedals to make it a balance bike might be a better starting option.  Useful read. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/what-are-the-conditions-for-removing-training-wheels

Answer (score 4):

Do the training wheel mounts look like this?

[image]

If so, the box can be removed allowing you to use other types of training wheels.

In the picture:

1. The white training wheels are removed by depressing the retention
   buttons and sliding the training wheel arm down.
2. With the training wheels removed the axle nut will be
   exposed allowing you to remove the nut with a socket wrench (pretty
   sure it's 15mm).
3. After removing the axle nut the box can be
   removed.

Repeat for the other side.

Answer (score 3):

The modern view is that training wheels aren't as helpful as they seem.

Instead, take the pedals, cranks, bottom bracket and chain off (or get a balance bike and store the big-kids bike)

Use the bike as a balance bike so the kid can "scooter" around and get used to the idea of balancing.

It may be convenient to occasionally take the child somewhere there's a gentle slope.  A park with a gradient can help provide the roll with less effort, making it more-fun.

Once the kid can roll for a good distance with feet up, while maintaining control, and perhaps expresses a desire to "ride with pedals like Mum" then swap back to pedals.